# OO Javascript / jQuery event click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new on JS developing, I'm trying to use OO Javascript using "classes", I have a class named "Timeblock", with it constructor:

```
var Timeblock = function(occupied, on, element) {
  this.occupied = occupied;
  this.on = on;
  this.room_id = 0;
  this.element= element;
}
```

I've created an object this way:

```
timeblock = new Timeblock(false, false, $('#element'));
```

Everything works at this point, now I'm trying to add a click event listener to the class constructor on its element var, I tried:

```
var Timeblock = function(occupied, on, element) {
  this.occupied = occupied;
  this.on = on;
  this.room_id = 0;
  this.element = element;

  timeblock = this;
  this.element.click(function() {
      timeblock.update();
  });
}

Timeblock.prototype.update = function() {
  if (!occupied) {
    this.element.addClass('on');
  }
}
```

When debugging in Chrome, I put a breakpoint on `this.element.addClass('on');` inspecting the object I can read `this.element: jQuery.fn.init[0]` and I can't get it to work.

Even in console when I type `this.element` I get `undefined`, but if I type `this.occupied`I get `false`

My question is, why I'm getting undefined? how can I make it work?, I've searched and searched but can't find any good material to study OO Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var Timeblock = function(occupied, on, element) {
  this.occupied = occupied;
  this.on = on;
  this.room_id = 0;
  this.element = element;

  var timeblock = this; // need var statement
  this.element.click(function() {
      timeblock.update();
  });
}

Timeblock.prototype.update = function() {
  if (!this.occupied) { // forgot this
    this.element.addClass('on');
  }
}
```

Two errors. I fixed them, and left comments explaining.

Comment: Thaks, it works, but why the var statement is needed?

Comment: Because otherwise it becomes a global, and is overwritten every time you initialize a new `Timeblock`.